# CMake - Undefined reference with static libraries / not with shared libraries

Tags: static, cmake, libraries, shared, ice

After having installed ZeroC Ice from source, I have static (.a) and shared (.so) libraries in my install/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu directory.

When I try to compile a program with CMake, every thing is fine when I write (in target_link_libraries) :

```
"${ICE_DIR}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIce.so"
"${ICE_DIR}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIceUtil.so"
```

But I get undefined reference when I try with static libraries :

```
"${ICE_DIR}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIce.a"
"${ICE_DIR}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIceUtil.a"
```

How could you explain that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get undefined references to these libraries or others? When the static libraries link against other shared libraries you have to link manually against then when you use the static one.

Comment: It is possible I get undefined references to others (I'm note sure). When I search the undefined symbol with "grep -r", I find that libIce.a and libIce.so.3.6.2 matches. "you have to link manually against then when you use the static one." -> How can I do that ?